# Constructing a JTree with infinite depth

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, jtree

If I don't know what is the depth of a jTree what logic I can employ to construct the JTree. I have a category table in my database with parent category and child within child and so on. I want to construct the JTree with that data. Can you give me some ideas of how to do this?  Following is my database structure.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own `TreeNode` which populates its list of the child nodes ad-hoc (by a DB query) when opening the node (i.e. upon the first call to `children()` or `getChildCount()`) instead of constructing a Tree of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`s in advance.

Also see the [Java tuorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) on this topic. The section *How to Load Children Lazily* shows a different approach using `TreeWillExpandListener`s and the detail topic [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html)

Comment: How do i get the path when i click on the little + on JTree. It is giving me null value when i click on tat because no path is selected. I want to populate the child on clicking on that +. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `JTree.addTreeExpansionListener` allows you to add a TreeExpansionListener that provides an event called `TreeExpansionEvent` when one of it's methods is called. Calling `getPath` on that event will tell you where you are.

BTW, if you are building a tree on the fly, you need to have + handles to begin with. This means when you put a node into the tree, you have to put a faux-node child below it. When you get a tree expansion event, see if that child node is one of these faux-nodes, and if it is, then remove it and replace it with the real children (based on the db query).

What is a Faux-Node? Just a class that implements TreeNode that is different in some way from your normal TreeNodes, that you can easily determine is what it is.

Comment: but anyways i am putting a child node called "Add" so that when clicked on tat will open a dialogue box and add a node to it. So do i have to add faux node in this case ? And i have one problem with adding nodes. When i add a node using dialogue box i cant see the changes even if i removed all the child node and add it again. what might be the problem ?

Comment: The Add node is the faux node in this case. When adding a node, you will probably have to fire an event that represents the change, such as `DefaultTreeModel.fireTreeNodesInserted(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices, Object[] children)`